# CVaListPointer when using objectsWhere() querying Realm database

Tags: ios, database, swift, realm, nspredicate

I'm updating my code to swift 3.0. I use Realm for the database. I have the following line of code:

```
let thisJob = Jobs.objectsWhere("identifier == '\(identify)'")
```

The compiler throws an error because an extra argument is required. "Missing argument for parameter 'args' in call" The parameter is a CVaListPointer. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use this argument. I tried:

```
let thisJob = Jobs.objectsWhere("identifier == '\(identify)'", args: CVaListPointer)
```

However, the compiler error with that line is "Cannot convert value of type CVaListPointer.Type to expected argument CVaListPointer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varargs in Objective-C interfaces aren't imported in Swift, which is why Realm has made a Swift wrapper for Realm Objective-C available: [RLMSupport.swift](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v1.1.0/Realm/Swift/RLMSupport.swift). Add that to your project's source files [as described in Realm's installation instructions](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation) and you'll be able to use `Jobs.objectsWhere("identifier == '\(identify)'")`.

Though if `identify` can at all contain characters that should be escaped when doing string interpolation, you're better off passing it as a format argument:

```
Jobs.objectsWhere("identifier == %@", identify)
```